# How to track result set size using hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, orm

I'm trying to detect and optimize inefficient joins within a Java/Hibernate application.  I've noticed that in some cases, due to the nature of how joins are handled in result sets, the over-the-wire data flow is very inefficient.

Let me provide an example.  Suppose you have an HQL query that looks like this:

```
select s from Store s
left join fetch s.items i
left join fetch s.employees e
left join fetch s.customers c
where s.id = :id
```

(Ignore for a moment that this is not a smart query - it's just a simplified example).

If you imagine that a given store has 1000 items and 10 employees and 100 customers, you will get back a java object tree with 1111 entities.  That might lull you into thinking that approximately 1111 rows were returned from the database, whereas in fact the result set had 1,000,000 rows!

The presence of all the columns makes this worse.  If you imagine that each table had 5 columns, you might imagine that you got approximately 5555 "items" back, whereas the number of cells (row * column) in the result set was actually 20,000,000.

Clearly, it is the application developer's responsibility to be aware of this issue and not write queries in that way.  However, this sometimes happens unintentionally (and in less severe ways), and it would be great to be able to instrument the application to somehow identify these situations.

However, I've been unable to find any way to calculate (from within a Java/Hibernate app) either the number of rows or the number of columns in the raw result set.  Neither Hibernate interceptors, Hibernate events, nor Hibernate statistics seem to give access to this information.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: well you could always use the same query but with count(*) before executing this :)

Comment: Yeah, that'll work, at the cost of (potentially) doubling the execution time for every query, so it's definitely an imperfect solution :)

Comment: can't query.list().size() give the count of records fetched ?

Comment: Doing a count won't double the execution time. It's not getting any actual data back from your database, just a single numeric result containing the number of rows. It shouldn't cause that much overhead for sensible queries. But those might not be the ones we're discussing here ;-)

Comment: Dhara - query.list().size() will give you the number of entities (in the above example, just one!) rather than the number of rows.  The example above is designed to show that there is no simple relationship between the two - in this case, one million rows vs. just one entity.

Comment: C. Monkey - Yes and no.  For example, if the query does a table scan, or creates temp tables, etc. it will do those things twice.  I agree that very little data gets transferred over the wire for a count(*), of course.

Comment: A suggestion for a slightly different, although DBMS-dependent approach: Identify the expensive queries using your database logs (e.g. using tkprof on your session trace for Oracle). That way, you can easily identify the most frequent and the most expensive queries.

Answer (score 2):

There's a project called [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) that provides a proxy JDBC driver, it can log SQL (with bind arguments added) as well as timing statistics, connection open and close events, even ResultSet calls. There are several forks, at least one (called [log4jdbc-remix](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc-remix/)) logs resultsets as tables.

I'd think using the `jdbc.sqltiming` logger should be enough to point out where problems are, then you can drill down with the other options if you need to. But it sounds do-able to hack on it to get resultset counts.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is a very complex framework. As you can see it consumes a lot of the overall execution time compared to raw JDBC. And your query not necesarally will create 1111 objects, because Hibernate makes use of caching, second level cache and other dark techiques to proxy objects and saves some memory, depending of the configuration, of course.

However, if you are looking to find any way to calculate some statistics from your Java code, you should use Hibernate Statistics, they are very useful in some cases, sure they didnt work for you?

```
QueryStatistics queryStats = stats.getQueryStatistics("from Store s");
queryStats.getCacheHitCount();
queryStats.getCacheMissCount();
queryStats.getCachePutCount();
queryStats.getExecutionCount();
queryStats.getExecutionAvgTime();
queryStats.getExecutionMaxTime();
queryStats.getExecutionMinTime();
queryStats.getExecutionRowCount();

SecondLevelCacheStatistics cacheStats = stats.getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("Sale.cache");
cacheStats.getElementCountInMemory();
cacheStats.getElementCountOnDisk();
cacheStats.getEntries();
cacheStats.getHitCount();
cacheStats.getMissCount();
cacheStats.getPutCount();
cacheStats.getSizeInMemory();

CollectionStatistics collectionStats = stats.getCollectionStatistics("Sale.items");
collectionStats.getFetchCount();
collectionStats.getLoadCount();
collectionStats.getRecreateCount();
collectionStats.getRemoveCount();
collectionStats.getUpdateCount();
```

And there are even more options to explore http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19807.html

Answer (score -1):

row count? "select count..." (its not like executing it twice. counts execute much quicker)
column count? Reflection.  fiddle with Class.getDeclaredMethods();